# The android ndk string splicing calls the malloc function. When I return the result to the JAVA layer, do I need to release it?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

The android ndk string splicing calls the malloc function. When I return the result to the JAVA layer, do I need to release it?
this is my code;

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

jstring test(JNIEnv *env, jstring ua, jstring pd) {
    const char *a = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, ua, NULL);
    const char *b = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, pd, NULL);
    const char *c = "@222";
    const char *d = "http://aaa=";
    const char *e = "&bbb=";
    const char *f = "&cc";
    char *host_0 = (char *) malloc(
            strlen(a) + strlen(b) + strlen(c) + strlen(d) +
            strlen(e) + strlen(f) + 1);
    strcpy(host_0, a);
    strcat(host_0, b);
    strcat(host_0, c);
    strcat(host_0, d);
    strcat(host_0, e);
    strcat(host_0, f);
//  free(host_0 ); release code
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, ua, a);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, pd, b);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, host_0);;
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_test_MainActivity_getString(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring a, jstring b) {
    return test(env,a,b);
}



//If you directly return the newStringUtf() function, will the memory be managed by the JVM? No longer need to release?
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_test_MainActivity_getString(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring a, jstring b) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "bbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}
```

1，When I was testing, if the free() function was not added, the native memory would take up hundreds of MB to run in a loop 100,000 times.And the memory cannot be reclaimed. It should be a memory leak. If the free() function is added, it is only about ten MB. But when I add the free() function, although the memory occupied by native is small, it may cause a crash. So I want to know. Do I need to release host_0?Where should I release host_0?

2，If you directly return the newStringUtf() function, will the memory be managed by the JVM? No longer need to release?

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  Second, why are you issuing a `free()` call before you actually utilize `host_0`?  Third -- what if `malloc` returns NULL?  Where is the error checking?

Comment: Yes. This is C code. I used malloc to allocate memory for host_0 in the test() method. When I finish splicing the string, do I need to call the free() function to release the host_0 variable allocated by malloc? This is just a demo code, so I didn't judge whether the allocation was successful. What I want to know is, if I do not call free() to release the variable host_0 allocated by malloc, will it cause a memory leak?

Comment: You have to free() the memory, otherwise there is a memory leak.  The problem is where you are freeing the memory, not if you have to free() the memory or not.  Second, look at the last line: `return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, host_0);;` -- Since `free()` was already issued, why are you attempting to use already `free()`-ed memory?

Comment: If it needs to be released, when should it be released? If I pass the host_0 variable directly through newStringUtf() and return to the java layer, will it be managed by the JVM at this time? I no longer need to deal with it? Will it cause memory leaks?

Comment: How will Java know how to free() the memory?  What if you used `new[]` instead?  Is Java going to know to call `delete[]`?  Of course not.  Thus it is solely your JNI layer's responsibility to release the memory.

Comment: Then when should I release host_0? In the last sentence, I have used the newStringUtf() function to return it to the getString() method. Returned to the Java layer by native getString(). I cannot arrange a suitable release location for host_0.

Comment: I have seen in other posts that if the newStringUtf() function is used to return the final value to the JAVA layer. At this time, the JVM will manage the memory. But as a result of my actual test, my memory will get bigger and bigger. It caused a memory leak and caused the app to crash. So I am confused whether to release or not.

Comment: [See this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewStringUTF) -- All you're providing is a string that the function will use to construct a Java `String`.  Nowhere in that documentation says where that string should come from.  From the documentation **from an array of characters in modified UTF-8 encoding**.  The function doesn't care where that array comes from.  Thus it is your C++ code that, for whatever reason, decided to use `malloc`.  You are solely responsible for calling `free()`, and it should be done after you've created the Java `String`.

Comment: ```
    char *host_0 = (char *) malloc(
            strlen(a) + strlen(b) + strlen(c) + strlen(d) +
            strlen(e) + strlen(f) + 1);

    jstring reCode = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, host_0);
    free(host_0);
    return reCode;
}```

Comment: I first use a jstring to receive the value of newStringUtf(host_0), and then release the host_0 allocated by malloc; can this code prevent the malloc function from allocating memory but not releasing it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223595/discussion-between-paulmckenzie-and-ajax).